# How to get primary contact account for organization uzing boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-organizations

I have a AWS Organization setup for my AWS accounts. I am looking for a method to programmatically get information about the primary contact for each of the accounts in my organization.

I have been using boto3 to get the data about accounts in organization. I am able to pull ARN, OUs, email etc. and I can store this data in an array.

I did some research and I can not find a method in Organizations class that will allow me to get this data.

Ref: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.42/reference/services/organizations.html

I did find a that I can pull this info using the account class but not for all accounts in the organization.

client = boto3.client('account')
get_contact_information(**kwargs)

Can you please help me to indentify method to pull this data about all accounts in the organizaitons? Also what permissions this method requires?

PS. I am able to access this using AWS portal
[image: example]

Comment: First, you can call `list_accounts`: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/organizations.html#Organizations.Client.list_accounts. Then, this seems to outline the access requirements to get contacts for accounts: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/account.html#Account.Client.get_contact_information.

Comment: Thanks Brian, I will give it a go and let you know if this approach worked for me.